# Android convert Location model to json string

Tags: android, json, kotlin, location, gson

I have a problem with converting the Location model to JSON string.

When I try to convert it With Gson to a string I lose the latitude and longitude fields.

```
...

location.lat = 40.00000 // example
location.lng = 29.00000 // example

val jsonString = Gson().toJson(location)
val newLocation = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Location::class.java)

Log.d(">>>>>>", "location lat is ${newLocation.lat} location lng is ${newLocation.lng} )
```

the result is 0.0 and 0.0

what is the problem?

**Update**

I know with a custom class I can handle this problem, but I'm curious why Location class not working.

Comment: Strange case. You can create a model class which hold lat long.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yes I did, but I wanna know the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using kotlin data class your code should work correctly.

```
data class Location(val lat: Double, val lng: Double)
```

```
val location = Location(40.0,29.0)
val locationJson = Gson().toJson(location)
val newLocation = Gson().fromJson(locationJson, Location::class.java)

Log.d(">>>>>>", "${newLocation.lat} : ${newLocation.lng}")
```

Comment: He  knows this process. He is curious about why   `Location` (Not custom class) class not working

Comment: see comment section `@IntelliJAmiya Yes I did, but I wanna know the problem.`